# Run a script after Bluetooth is configured and running - Rasperry Pi 3

Tags: bluetooth, raspberry-pi, raspbian, raspberry-pi3

I'm trying to automatically call a program at boot that uses Bluetooth. However, the program is being called before Bluetooth is configured and running.

I've tried calling the program in two ways:

1. Using a script in init.d and registered with update-rc.d with this line in the init: `# Required-Start:    $all`
2. Calling it from /etc/rc.local

Neither of these work as desired. They both start the program, but before Bluetooth is configured and running.

What is the best way to force a script or program to run after Bluetooth?

Below are some select lines from the boot sequence so you can see the issue I'm having:

```
[ OK ] Started Login Service.
[ OK ] Started Getty on tty1.
**Where my program is currently executing**
[ OK ] Started Configure Bluetooth Modems connected by UART.
[ OK ] Reached Target Bluetooth
**Where I want my program to be executing**

Raspbian GNU/Linux 8 tty1
login:
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The new init system for Debian 8 "Jessie" is systemd. The old way in Debian 7 "Wheezy" was Sysv with runlevels and `/etc/inittab`. A drawback of using `crontab` to run your program will be, if the script execution crashes, it dies forever. Restarting a script automatically if its ends is called "respawn".

As you can see, the Bluetooth Service is running and prints that a "Target" is reached. To create your own service, which runs after bluetooth startup, and respawns with systemd just create a file in `/etc/systemd/system/` i.e. `my_program.service`

```
[Unit]
Desription=my_program with systemd, respawn, after bluetooth
After=bluetooth.target

[Service]
ExecStart=node /home/pi/workspace/my_program
Restart=always

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

and activate it

```
systemctl enable my_program.service
```

reboot or start it manually

```
systemctl daemon-reload
systemctl start my_program.service
```

If one kills the process or reboots, `my_program` will be restarted automatically some seconds later.

Comment: Just as an extra note: the Bluetooth service must be enabled (systemctl enable Bluetooth) so that Bluetooth boots before my_program.

Answer (score 3):

For anyone running Raspbian 9 (stretch)

I tried out @andpei's answer and my application still wasn't waiting for bluetooth to start up. I was able to solve this by adding "Requires".

```
[Unit]
Desription=my_program with systemd, respawn, after bluetooth
After=bluetooth.target
Requires=bluetooth.target
```

Comment: didn't work for me, I had to use multi-user.target instead of bluetooth.target   https://discourse.osmc.tv/t/command-to-make-systemd-wait-for-system-time-to-be-updated/36676/9

Answer (score 0):

Using crontab, I was able to make it work with the following line:

```
@reboot sleep 5 && node /home/pi/workspace/my_program
```

Not ideal but it works for now. I'm open to any better answers.